# Installing wireless driver (realtek 8188CE) on Debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, wifi

I had a hard time installing the wireless driver for my debian. My debian was Sqeeze but soon after I realized Wheezy was the one to support my wireless adapter, realtek 8188CE,I upgraded to wheezy. Here is my `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

I followed the exact steps [listed on the Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x#Wheezy).
At step 4, after I typed in iwconfig,there was no tag for wifi (shouldn't it be there?), I figured the wifi module was not loaded, but I didn't know how to check and add it

Here is my printout:

```
clint@Thinkpad-W520:~$ lspci | grep -i wifi
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE      802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

The `iwconfig` output:

```
lo no wireless extensions.

eth0 no wireless extensions.

pan0 no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It went perfect for me:

#### For starters list what pci devices are currently present

```
% lspci
....

07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

#### Modify /etc/apt/sources.list

```
% deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
```

#### install updates

```
% apt-get update
```

#### install realtek & wireless tools

```
% apt-get install firmware-realtek wireless-tools
```

#### confirm wirelss is working

```
% iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading this, Wheezy used to be the testing branch at the time this answer was written. Nowadays, Wheezy is the stable branch so `testing` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` up there would refer to Jessie.

Answer (score 1):

Never for any reason should be mixed repositories from Debian stable with testing branch. However you can add in your repositories backport repository and then you can get a newer kernel to work with RTL8188CE Realtek driver