# My Wifi wont work on my Debian laptop

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

Some Questions from someone new to Debian:

1. I have tried to install some wifi detecting programs,but i don't think the driver is installed... How do i find and install the driver?
2. I have tried to follow the instructions on Debian's website but
   could not find the answer there, it was too confusing for me.
3. I'm also looking for help in installing the packages...

As requested, here are my network drivers...

`sudo lspci | grep controller`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

When i do `iwconfig` I get the output

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

**Update**
I have followed all the things eyoung100 has told me to do in his answer. He has some of the research in there as well. I still do not have the WIFI working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the [pciutils](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=pciutils) package.  Use the command `lspci`. Post the output of `lspci` in your question using the Edit Link, and I'll help you install the driver after we know what it is.
2. Read this [Beginner's Guide to Debian](http://www.aboutdebian.com/)
3. Read the [Official Debian Manual on Aptitude](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html), the Debian Package Manager.  You might want to do this one first, even though you asked it last.

Although this answer is quite direct, here is the best piece of advice I can give you.  Now that you've switched to Linux, you'll find varying degrees of expertise, but people in all those levels will expect you to do something that is unheard of in the Windows World.  All installed Linux Commands come with a man page.  To use it, type `man` and the command you'd like to learn about.  Some great examples include:

- `man ls`
- `man apt`
- `man man`

### Update

According to `lspci`, this is your Wireless Card:

> 02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE
>   Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

and now that you've read the [Official Debian Manual on Aptitude](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html), you should be able to follow [this post also on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49260/installing-wireless-driver-realtek-8188ce-on-debian-wheezy).  Skip over adding the testing branch while reading the post from user30349.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18863/discussion-on-answer-by-eyoung100-my-wifi-wont-work-on-my-debian-laptop).